# android fragment transaction lifecycle not called when remove

Tags: android, android-lifecycle, fragmenttransaction

someone can help me to understand why the lifecycle method Stop and Destroy are not called with fragment manager transaction when you use a single transaction add/ remove ?
I have a single container ( RelativeLayout ) in which I can add or remove many fragments. Case with only two fragments. Fragment_A is already added in previous transaction.

now if I do this below, everything works fine: The lifecycle methode OnPause and OnDestroy of fragment_A are called.

```
FragmentTransaction transaction = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
transaction.add(myId, fragmentB);
trasaction.commit();
FragmentTransaction transaction = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
transaction.remove(fragmentA);
trasaction.commit();
```

if I do this below, the lifecycle method OnPause, OnDestroy are never fired for fragment A ( I checked the fragment inside the manager and the fragments are well added / removed ):

```
FragmentTransaction transaction = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
transaction.add(myContainerId, fragmentB);
transaction.remove(fragmentA);
trasaction.commit();
```

I tried to use transaction.setResorderAllowed(false) but whatever, my lifecycle doesn't go until destroy with single transaction. ( I can not use replace, I really need add/remove )

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Where do you check whether the lifecycle states are changed? `commit()` is asynchronous, so anything you check immediately afterwards won't have been updated yet.

Comment: I have some listener attached to the lifecycle doing some stuff OnPause and OnDestroy. First case 2 different transaction, no problem they are fired. Add and remove in the same transaction, the removed fragment doesn't go to stop and destroy lifecycle. If I read the state manually when the fragment is not in the manager, the fragment never quit Resumed state. For now, I solved my issue by using two transactions but that bother me :) since one should be enough.

Comment: Would it work if you remove fragmentA first and then add fragmentB in that order?

Comment: I tried too :) That's the same. If you do Add / Remove or Remove / Add in the same transaction, the removed fragment stuck in the resumed state. I'll tried one day to do a simple code to check. For now,  gonna stay in double transaction, one for add and one for remove. Maybe there is something in my full code that's make this failed. But if someone did it and it suppose to work, I'll like to know. No time to waste on this. Thanks anyway.